# An identity about Vandermonde determinant.

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, determinant, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

I want to prove the following identity

$\sum_{i=1}^{k}x_i\Delta(x_1,\ldots,x_i+t,\ldots,x_k)=\left(x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_k+{k \choose 2}t\right)\cdot\Delta(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k),$

where we write 
$\Delta(l_1,\ldots,l_k)$ for $\prod_{i<j}(l_i-l_j).$

I have checked that this identity is true for $k=2,3.$
I tried to calculate LHS using Vandermonde determinant,
but it seems to work.
I sense some properties of symmetric function could be useful……
Any help will be appreciated.:)

---

The problem comes from Fulton's book "Young Tableaux-With Applications to Representation Theory and Geometry".
It's a default fact in Exercise 10 in page55.

[image]

However, I cannot prove this.

---

He uses the following fact to prove Hook length formula.
[image]

And set $x_i=l_i$ and $t=-1$ in Exercise 10.

Comment: I have been interested in a nice proof of this identity for a while! (I remember there being a proof using root counting, but I don't remember the details, except that I didn't like them.) This sounds like it could have a combinatorial meaning (RS insertion in some tableau?).

Comment: I am interested in how this identity leads to the Hook Length formula; could you or someone else sketch the rest of the argument?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Fulton's book uses the fact of  Exercise 9 in page54.

Answer (score 2):

The difference of the RHS and the  LHS is a degree $\binom{k}{2}+1$ polynomial in $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k, t$.

First, note that if $x_i=x_j$ for any $i, j$, then the equation is true.  Indeed, the RHS would be 0, and all terms on the LHS would be 0 other than $x_i\Delta(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_i+t, \ldots, x_k)$ and $x_j\Delta(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_j+t, \ldots, x_k)$, which cancel out (all factors not involving $x_i$ and $x_j$ are the same; factors involving only one can be paired up as $(x_i+t-x_k)(x_k-x_j)$ which is the same as $(x_i-x_k)(x_k-(x_j+t))$(recall $x_i=x_j$), and the only factors left are $x_i+t-x_j$ and $x_i-(x_j+t)$, causing one to be the opposite of the other).

Therefore, $x_i-x_j$ is a factor of the difference for any $i, j$, giving $\binom{k}{2}$ factors.

When $t=0$, the equation is true by the distributive law.  So $t$ is also a factor of the difference of the LHS and the RHS.

Therefore, the difference LHS-RHS must be of the form $Ct\prod_{i<j}{(x_i-x_j)}$ for some constant $C$.  To prove that $C=0$, it sufficies to show that the equation is true for some values for $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_k,t$ where no two $x_i$ are equal and $t\neq0$.

I will choose $x_i=i$ and $t=-1$.

$$\textrm{LHS}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}i\Delta(1,\ldots, i-1,i-1,i+1,\ldots,k),$$

and all terms are 0 except the first, which is $\Delta(0,2,\ldots,k).$

$$\textrm{RHS}=\left(1+2+\ldots+k+\binom{k}{2}(-1)\right)\cdot\Delta(1,2,\ldots,k)=k\Delta(1,2,\ldots,k).$$

So, the goal is to show

$$\Delta(0,2,\ldots,k)=k\Delta(1,2,\ldots,k).$$

To do this, note that all the factors in the $\Delta$ part not involving the first term are the same in both.  For the LHS, the factors involving the first term are $-2,-3,\ldots,-k$, and for the RHS, the factors involving the first term are $-1,-2,\ldots,-(k-1)$, so we are done.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** There exists a solution without the polynomial identity trick; it is long but rather conservative in its methods:

- Fix some $i$. Vandermonde tells us that $\Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_i + t, \ldots, x_k\right)$ is the determinant of the $k\times k$-matrix whose $\left(u,v\right)$-th entry is $x_u^{k-v}$ if $u \neq i$ and $\left(x_i+t\right)^{k-v}$ if $u = i$.
- Expand this determinant along the $i$-th row. Do the same with $\Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\right)$. Notice that the cofactors will be the same for both determinants.
- In the expansion of $\Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_i + t, \ldots, x_k\right)$, expand each $\left(x_i + t\right)^{k-v}$ by the binomial formula: $\left(x_i + t\right)^{k-v} = \sum\limits_{\ell=0}^{k-v} \dbinom{k-v}{\ell} t^\ell x_i^{k-v-\ell}$.
- Subtract $\Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\right)$; this steals one addend from the binomial formula (i.e., the $\sum\limits_{\ell=0}^{k-v} \dbinom{k-v}{\ell} t^\ell x_i^{k-v-\ell}$ is turned into $\sum\limits_{\ell=1}^{k-v} \dbinom{k-v}{\ell} t^\ell x_i^{k-v-\ell}$).
- Conclude a double sum expression for $\Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_i + t, \ldots, x_k\right) - \Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\right)$. Multiply it by $x_i$ and sum over all $i$. The result is a triple sum (i.e., a sum of sums of sums). Your goal is to prove that this result is $\dbinom{k}{2} t \Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\right)$.
- Transform the triple sum so that the summation over $i$ becomes the innermost sum. Then, the sum over $i$ is a Laplace expansion of a certain determinant with respect to the $i$-th row. If $\ell=1$, then this latter determinant is $\Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\right)$, whereas otherwise it is zero (since it has two equal rows). Use this to get rid of the two inner sums. The outer sum now becomes $\sum\limits_{v=1}^{k} \dbinom{k-v}{1} t \Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\right) = \dbinom{k}{2} t \Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\right)$, which is what you wanted.

The details can be found in the solution to Exercise 6.34 in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra* (version of 10 January 2019)](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10) (there is also a [version on my website which is being kept up-to-date](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/primes2015/sols.pdf), but its numbering might shift).

**2.** I am wondering if there is a combinatorial proof (by sign-reversing involution). Combinatorial proofs of the Vandermonde determinant can be found in various places:

- [Arthur T. Benjamin and Gregory P. Dresden, *A Combinatorial Proof of Vandermonde's Determinant*, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 114, No. 4 (Apr., 2007), pp. 338–341](https://web.archive.org/web/20160729183227/http://home.wlu.edu/~dresdeng/papers/VDM.pdf).
- Martin Aigner, *A Course in Enumeration*, Graduate Texts in Mathematics #238, Springer 2007, §5.3.
- Nicholas A. Loehr, *Bijective Combinatorics*, Chapman & Hall/CRC 2011, §12.9.
- Ira Gessel, *Tournaments and Vandermonde's Determinant*, Journal of Graph Theory, Vol. 3 (1979), pp. 305–307. There is a sketch in [a talk by David Bressoud](http://www.macalester.edu/~bressoud/talks/2012/Bijections.pdf) and probably in [a followup paper by Bressoud](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0195-6698(87)80028-8).

**3.** Here are four variations on the identity from the original post:

> *Variation 1.* We have
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum\limits_{i=1}^k \Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_i + t, \ldots, x_k\right) = k \Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\right) .
> \end{equation}
>
> *Variation 2.* For each $i \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,k\right\}$, set $y_i = \prod\limits_{1\leq j\leq k;\ j \neq i} x_j$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum\limits_{i=1}^k y_i \Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_i + t, \ldots, x_k\right) = - \dfrac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^k \left(x_i-t\right) - \prod\limits_{i=1}^k x_i}{t} \Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\right) .
> \end{equation}
>
> *Variation 3.* For each $m \in \left\{0,1,\ldots,k-1\right\}$, we have
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum\limits_{i=1}^k x_i^m \Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{i-1}, t, x_{i+1}, \ldots, x_k\right) = t^m \Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\right) .
> \end{equation}
>
> *Variation 4.* For each $i \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,k\right\}$, set $y_i = \prod\limits_{1\leq j\leq k;\ j \neq i} x_j$. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \sum\limits_{i=1}^k y_i \Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_{i-1}, t, x_{i+1}, \ldots, x_k\right) = - \dfrac{\prod\limits_{i=1}^k \left(x_i-t\right) - \prod\limits_{i=1}^k x_i}{t} \Delta\left(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k\right) .
> \end{equation}

Variation 1 is easier than the original problem. It has an algebraic proof which is similar to (but easier than) the above argument (Proposition 7.192 in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10)). I am wondering whether it has a combinatorial proof using tournaments as well.

Variation 2, on the other hand, appears significantly harder. I have two proofs. One uses the alternant expression for the elementary symmetric functions. Another is more elementary but irritatingly long (see Proposition 7.198 and Proposition 7.199 **(d)** in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10)). A combinatorial proof would be particularly interesting here.

Variation 3 is fairly easy again (it is Proposition 7.194 in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10)). It is also equivalent (when the denominators make sense) to the famous formula $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k x_i^m \dfrac{\prod\limits_{j \neq i} \left(t-x_j\right)}{\prod\limits_{j \neq i} \left(x_i-x_j\right)} = t^m$, which can be seen as an explicit description of a Lagrange interpolating polynomial. Again, I don't have a combinatorial proof.

Variation 4 is again painful to prove (Proposition 7.205 in [my *Notes on the combinatorial fundamentals of algebra*](https://github.com/darijgr/detnotes/releases/tag/2019-01-10)).